# Set text input to focus when I press a button with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have a search button on the page, and when users press the search button, the search bar comes into the screen and I would also like to set the input to focus as well. Can I do this with pure CSS3?

Here is the code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Search_Button" /> <!-- Opens Search Bar -->

<label for="Search_Button">
    <div id="Search_Container" class="Button_Container">
        <img src="SVG/Search.svg" class="Button" id="Search" />
    </div> 
</label>
```

Here you can see the CSS styling so that the search bar is pushed off the screen:

```
#Search_Box {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 8vh;
    background-color: #38D1A9;
    transform: translate3d(0, -8vh, 0);
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}
```

Here is the search box that drops down:

```
<div id="Search_Box">
    <input type="search" name="Search" id="Search_Input" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
```

So here is the issue. I have a search icon displayed. When the search icon is pressed, it brings down the "Search_Box" which has the search input inside it. I would like to, when that search icon is pressed, immediately make that search box focused.

The issue with a label technique is that, while it works exactly as intended, the search icon is already inside a label (this label it sits inside is to bring down the search box into view), so I won't be able to wrap it in another label.

I tried to do this:

```
#Search_Button:checked ~ div #Search_Input {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I tried saying that when the Search_Button was checked, it would bring the search input to focus, but it's definitely not the way to do it. I'm trying to avoid using JS if I can because I'm working on mobile.

I really apologize for any confusion!

Comment: You can't set focus with CSS, but otherwise yes. If you want a better answer, you'll need to provide some markup and styles that demonstrates an attempt.

Comment: your HTML isn't making much sense to me. there is no `input type="text"` element anywhere in it, and your use of the label element seems to serve no purpose. can you enlighten me?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Sorry for the confusion...I just added everything!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with native HTML behavior by associating a `label` element with the `input` element. Set the `label` element's `for` attribute equal to the `input` element `id` attribute value. When the `label` element is clicked, the `input` element will be focused on.

#### Example without JavaScript:

```css
label {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}
```

```html
<label for="focus-input">Button</label>
<p>Other elements...</p>
<input type="text" id="focus-input" />
```

It's worth mentioning that the CSS above isn't required. It was only added to make the `label` element appear at a button. Feel free to style the `label` element however you want. In certain cases, you can even wrap it around other elements.

**Alternative example with different styling:**

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="focus-input">Button</label>
<p>Other elements...</p>
<input type="text" id="focus-input" />
```

---

#### Alternative example with JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('focus-input').focus();
});
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<p>Other elements...</p>
<input type="text" id="focus-input" />
```

Comment: +1. it's worth mentioning that the CSS isn't necessary at all for the functionality (this is the native behavior of the label element in nearly every browser), it only styles the label to look like a button.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer! The issue I now have is that the search icon I'm using is already a label because it pulls down the search bar. I'm going to add the code so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I added the code! Also might be note worthy to say that this will be for mobile. I only say that because I am unsure if that makes a difference with cursor: pointer.

Comment: @KodyR. It's unclear what you're trying to do based on the HTML that you provided... Where is the input `type="text"` element? I made a quick example - http://jsfiddle.net/5uy80260/